# InvalidArgumentException composer when installing laravel package via composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've created a package in laravel with laravel packager, I push it to my github account and also submit to Packagist. When I hit

```
composer require mortezarajabi/jdate
```

in root directory, I get the

```
    [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
      Could not find package mortezarajabi/jdate at any version for your minimum-  
      stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

and this is my composer

```
{
    "name": "mortezrajabi/jdate",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Jalali(Falaki) date for laravel",
    "keywords": [
        "mortezarajabi",
        "jdata"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/mortezarajabi/jdate",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "mortezarajabi",
            "email": "emortezarajabi@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://mortezarajabi.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "~5",
        "php" : ">=5.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "rajabi\\jdate\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Have you created at least one tag for this project in Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have any `tag` for your package in Git. Packagist uses **tags** for package versioning. It will use your latest tag as a default version in `composer require mortezarajabi/jdate`.

So if you just want to work with `master` branch, you can require it in your **composer.json** as follow:

```
"require": { "mortezarajabi/jdate" : "dev-master" }
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

And then you can:

```
composer update
```